# Could this $100000004$ digits number be candidate for the record prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's observe following number :

> $ 4517\cdot 2^{332192811}+1$

I have noticed  :

If $k\cdot 2^{2n+1}+1$ is prime number then $\gcd(k-1,3)=1$ , where $k,n \in Z^{+}$ , so

$\gcd(k-1,3)=1$ should be a necessary condition.

Since $\gcd(4516,3)=1$ this condition is fulfilled.

[Proth weight](http://www.brennen.net/primes/ProthWeight.html) of coefficient $4517$ is $w \approx 0.98199 $ which may be considered to be high value.

I would like to know are there some other necessary conditions that this number has to satisfy , so that might be considered like candidate for prime number ?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica:

> 1: PrimeQ[$4517\cdot2^{332192811} + 1$]
>
> 2: False

I guess they use the [Miller-Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Comment: Thanks..I know that it is easy to test number using a computer...but I would like to know are there some theoretical conditions similar to the conditions that I mentioned in the text of the question..

Comment: Did you look up the wikipedia page I linked? The Miller-Rabin test actually relies on such conditions which are true for primes.

Comment: Put another way: Miller-Rabin is in fact a *compositeness* test. If `PrimeQ[]` returns `False`, the number is definitely composite.

Comment: I think that there must be more similar conditions..